# Given a class name, how do I get its class object?

Tags: javascript, class, eval, classname

After I have evaled:
`class myclass{}`,
I want to get that class object, given its name.
When you eval:
`function myfn(){}`
You can do:
`window.myfn`
and
`globalThis["myfn"]`
to get the function object.
But for getting the class object, this doesn't work.
I can do:
`eval("myclass")`
to get the class object,
but many stackoverflow responders don't like using eval.
Is there another way to do it?

Comment: you can create an object and use a class expression to add it: `classes['myclass'] = class {}`, this way you can avoid eval-like code

Comment: "*After I have evaled: `class myclass{}`*" - why exactly are you using `eval` in the first place? But if it really makes sense in your use case, then `eval("myclass")` is just as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Function()` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Function) to create a new class and assign that value to a global variable:

```js
const className = 'myclass';

window[className] = new Function(`class ${className}{}; return ${className}`)()

console.log(myclass)
```

Comment: There's various tricks that I, as the application programmer, can set up data structures to "manually" remember the association between the class and its classname. But I was hoping JS would do this for me in a similar fashion that it does for function definitions and their names. From the responses to my post, I guess not. I can understand why classnames could pollute the global namespace, but certainly less than function names already do. Oh well. Thanks to the responders for validating my fears about this JS deficiency.